# Golang Slice Resizing. Smaller in two directions but larger possible only in one?

Tags: go, slice

I am just wondering, why it is apparently not possible to completely restore a resized slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d slice=%v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    fmt.Println("address of 0th element:", &s[0])

    s = s[1:4]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d slice=%v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    fmt.Println("address of 0th element:", &s[0])

    // extend behind only ...
    s = s[:4]
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d slice=%v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
    fmt.Println("address of 0th element:", &s[0])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4Hwq9yfHeRR

So to get the first element (1) again. This may be helpful in some cases.
I have read https://blog.golang.org/slices ... but I do not understand
why they have it done this way. To store the starting position and the
the 0th element of an array "sounds simple".

I have the feeling that I do not understand something correctly or
or that I overlooked something.

Comment: Read the documentation: [Go: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) : Why does Go not have feature X?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_doesnt_Go_have_feature_X), "sounds simple" is not valid argument.

Comment: @peterSO I have written "I have the feeling that I do not understand something correctly or or that I overlooked something." If there is no response, I will accept it, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because slice struct only has a pointer to the first element, integer length and integer capacity.

You can see slice runtime representation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader).

So if we assign a new slice to the same variable we will lose the elements located before the new first element `s = s[1:4]`, but if assign `s = s[:4]` we will not lose the capacity of slice.

**Note:** You still can get lost items with reflection and pointer arithmetic but it unsafe, and strongly unrecommended.